# Best syntax for reusing (anonymous) record values

Tags: syntax, f#

`f` is a function which returns a (anonymous) record, e.g.:

```
let f a b c =
    {| X = a + b; Y = c; Z = 1|}
```

What's the syntax to change an element based on its current value without asigning it to another binding before?

```
let x1 = {| f a b c with Y = Y + 12 |} 
//                           ^ The value or constructor 'Y' is not defined.
```

Especially in more complex situations, e.g.:

```
let x2 = if a + b < c 
         then {| X = a; Y = c + b; Z = 1 |}
         else {| f a b c with Y = Y + 12 |}
//                                ^ The value or constructor 'Y' is not defined.
```

---

I would like to see something like an alias. **Does such a thing exist?**

```
let x2 = if a + b < c 
         then {| X = a; Y = c + b; Z = 1 |}
         else {| (f a b c) as y with Y = y.Y + 12 |}
//                         ^^^^          ^^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact syntax you're suggesting doesn't exist, but this is exactly what `let` does:

```
let x2 = if a + b < c 
         then {| X = a; Y = c + b; Z = 1 |}
         else let y = f a b c in {| y with Y = y.Y + 12 |}
```

---

In your question you say "*without assigning it to another binding*", but your last example does just that: it binds `f a b c` to `y` (which is why this is exactly what `let` does).

This makes me think that by "another binding" you meant something more specific than just a binding. Perhaps if you clarify what that is, and, more importantly, why exactly doesn't it work for you, we may come up with a better solution.

Comment: I was searching for `in`. I am still learning F# and did not stumbled over it so far. Thank you!